# Help with html table layout

Tags: html

I want to show the below layout using html tables.

```
 foo      : jack
 products : bag
            bat
            ball
            shoes
 blah     : olah
```

I tried this but its not working as my expectations.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <th>row 1</th>
  <td> Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>row 1</th>
  <td>
  <table>
  <tr>foo1</tr>
  <tr>foo2</tr>
  </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>row 1</th>
  <td> Hello</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Ahhm, the elements in your HTML are not the same that you wanted to display?!

Comment: this is just a demo i was trying..

Comment: I have no clue why you use nested tables. And regarding tables for layout have a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be a `table`? It seems that something like a definition list *might* be more appropriate to your usage, so I'd suggest the following as an option:

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Foo:</dt>
    <dd>Jack</dd>
    <dt>Products:</dt>
    <dd>Bag</dd>
    <dd>Bat</dd>
    <dd>Ball</dd>
    <dd>Shoes</dd>
    <dt>Blah:</dt>
    <dd>Olah</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
dt, dd {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
dt {
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
}
dd {
    width: 49%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 51%;
}

dt + dd {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    position: relative;
}

dt + dd:before {
    content: " : ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -1em;
}
```

And the [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/k7zfC/2/).

Comment: A *real answer*, eh? As opposed to..? =b But thank you! I'm glad to have helped, some. Even if I have given you completely different mark-up than you wanted to work with... =D

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be achieved by using rowspan

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using many way, but i just create it in quick way.

http://jsfiddle.net/dXU8D/

```
 <table width="300" border="1">
 <tr>
   <td width="88">foo      : </td>
    <td width="196">jack</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td height="99">products : </td>
<td><table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td height="59">4</td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="23">blah     : </td>
    <td>olah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you can use rowspan to achieve this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Mzyzx/

```
<table width="300" border="1">
 <tr>
<td width="88">foo      : </td>
<td width="196">jack</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td height="99" rowspan="5">products : </td>
<td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="23">blah     :</td>
  <td>olah</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: using pre and counting the spaces yourself is not very flexible if the length of the strings in the first column changes. Also you might not like the font used for pre.

Comment: well thanks for replying but i can see u have some fixed height of 59 ...just i was curious what if the list products i am not aware of the list size beforehand and thenit would look odd...in addition what if i don't have table borders...it won't look good in this case case...what will look good is that the products tag should be with the starting product.

Comment: Hi this is just an example, the questioner want to just diplay the data,

Comment: There is better way of doing that using div, etc,. but the question is pretend to learn this stuff. i just create it in dreamviever

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, in your embedded table...

```
<table>
    <tr>foo1</tr>
    <tr>foo2</tr>
</table>
```

...you forgot to also wrap them in `<td>` elements:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>foo1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>foo2</td></tr>
</table>
```

But then, of course, you have the problem where the corresponding `<th>` is aligned in the middle of the table cell, instead of the top. But that can be fixed with the `valign` property:

```
<th valign="top">row 1</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>foo</td><td>:</td><td>jack</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td>products</td><td>:</td><td>bag</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td/><td>bat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td/><td>ball</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><td/><td>shoes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>blah</td><td>:</td><td>olah</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Produces:

[image]

The key is that the colons are in a column of their own.

Comment: just a quick question like the above thing will not work if i have a list of products....

Comment: i mean i am gonna iterate over the list and create all html elements for products...seems not possible for above html..

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 70%;">foo</td><td style="width: 10%;">:</td><td style="width: 20%;">jack</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>products </td><td>:</td><td>bag</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>bat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>ball</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td>shoes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td><td>:</td><td>olah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

one more example to be complete. http://jsfiddle.net/2ufsD/